# ParseException: Unparseable date in a custom method for parsing dates

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I wrote a method to parse a date. When I'm passing the following date as an argument `2019-03-05 06:15:00`, I'm getting a `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2019-03-05 06:15:00"`.

What could be wrong with the logic?

```
public String convertDate(String val) throws ParseException {
    return "cast('" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").format(
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'").parse(val)) + "' as ts)";
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also don’t use `'Z'` in your format pattern string to parse or print `Z` as a literal. `Z` (pronounced *Zulu*) means UTC and needs to be parsed or printed as such, or you will get wrong results.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to obtain? It seems like you are dynamically generating an SQL expression or similar. For the vast majority of purposes that would be more complicated than what you really need. See [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse string `2019-03-05 06:15:00` using pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'` that obviously does not fit.

Comment: I've tried to pass the following string:`2013-06-19T12:00-05:00` and still getting a  `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-06-19T12:00-05:00"`

Comment: @samba still the string you are trying to parse is not matching the pattern, check the time part

Comment: Try `2013-06-19T12:00Z`, this is what should probably work.

Comment: Define “work”. It will not throw an exception, but will give an incorrect result (on most JVMs).

Answer (score 1):

Either change the method to following

```
public String convertDate(String val) throws ParseException {
        return "cast('" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'").format(
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").parse(val)) + "' as ts)";
}
```

or pass

```
2019-03-05T06:15Z
```

Comment: I need to leave the method as-is. Instead I want to understand what kind of string should I pass

Comment: Pass 2019-03-05T06:15Z

Comment: thanks! The problem was that I've passed date string incompatible with my pattern

Comment: @samba Wrong! The Z is the zone offset! Not just a letter. Your pattern doesn't reflect what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The `Z` represents the zone offset. Per documentation

```
Z zone-offset offset-Z +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```

So your `String` should be, for example

```
2019-03-05T06:15+0100
```

Your patterns **doesn't seem to reflect** what you want to accomplish. Z isn't just a simple letter.

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ
```

Anyway, avoid using `SimpleDateFormat`, use `DateTimeFormatter` instead, which is part of the new Time API for Java 8.

```
final String val = "2019-03-05T06:15+0100";
final TemporalAccessor parse = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ").parse(val);
final String format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS").format(parse);
```

---

By inputting

```
2019-03-05T06:15+01:00
```

you could even just use

```
final TemporalAccessor parsed = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(val);
```

Comment: @MS90 didn't know that. Thanks. Well lets hope OP is from Germany then ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing is wrong with your code except for this SS and change the order too.

> s       second-of-minute            number        55
>
> S      fraction-of-second          fraction      978

```
   public static String convertDate(String val) throws ParseException {
    return "cast('" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'").format(
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(val)) + "' as ts)";
}
```

Comment: I presume T is for Tag( day ), and Z is for Zeit ( time ) ?

Comment: No, @MS90. T is for time (denotes where the time of day starts) and Z is the military name for “Zulu time zone” or UTC or UTC offset zero.

Comment: The answer is here: [ISO 8601 on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ([Z here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) and [T here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations)). But please wait for samba to confirm, of course.